# How to auto create folder based on filename and move the file into it's folder using .BAT

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

I have already solved my question... What I haven't solved is how to do this if the `.bat` file is located in a parent folder and that it should work on all subfolders?

Right now, there's a limitation that it only create folders if the `.bat` file is located in the same folder as the files. It can't create folders if the files are inside a subfolder.

What I have is:

the filename of this `.bat` is :

**organize.bat**

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*) do (
 if not "%%~ni" == "organize" (
  md "%%~ni" && move "%%~i" "%%~ni"
 )
)
```

How I do it right now:

1. I place the `.bat` file in a folder together with the files
2. When I click it, it will create folders with a name based on the files inside that folder
3. It will also move each files in those folders of the same name

What I need:

1. Place the `.bat` file in the main folder with many subfolders containing the files
2. Click it to perform the same tasks above

Apologies if my explanation is confusing... I hope it's still understandable.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28921039/62576

Comment: Open a command Prompt window, type `for /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key, to learn the available command options.

Comment: You should change `&&` to `&` since the former skips the following command if the directory already exists but the latter does not…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is very close to working but beware the wrinkles of using a simple approach without checking each detail so, start here:-

```
@echo off & Title %~n0
REM I recommend using cd /d "%~dp0" to ensure you start from the known cmd file folder location not some system folder
cd /D "%~dp0"

REM clear the second-pass file from any previous run
del second-pass.bat

REM add the /R switch to run through subdirs
for /R %%i in (*) do (

REM This is a relatively simple slow approach. So there will be repeats for make dir and
REM not all files will always need a move, so you should check the contents prior to run the second-pass.bat

REM replace organize to %~n0 so as to aid renaming by other users
 if not "%%~DPni" == "%~DPn0" (
REM to allow for nested paths we need a fuller DP location for N (check it works exactly as desired then remove the echos)
  echo md "%%~DPni" >>second-pass.bat && echo move "%%~i" "%%~DPni" >>second-pass.bat
 )
)
```

BEWARE files with double .dot.s such as cmd.exe.lnk so check those echo's first

```
md "C:\Users\me\Favorites\Links\cmd.exe"
move "C:\Users\me\Favorites\Links\cmd.exe.lnk" "C:\Users\me\Favorites\Links\cmd.exe"
```

Comment: First, thanks a lot for taking the time to write such a helpful answer! It worked exactly how I need it to be. Although one problem that I knew would happen is that it created several repetitive folders for each file (at least 8 levels (folders) for the same file). Do you know if it's possible to prevent creating duplicate folders? If not, it's alright, you're still very helpful! Thank you!